# Localising the date value in Angular Material datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

I'm working with Angular Material date picker. My problem is that when I send a date to the Web Api controller, I get a date less than the date I have selected in my form. I think this is due to the fact that the date value is not being localized. What I want to know is that how to **localize** the **date** in **angular js**

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-controller="AppCtrl" style='padding: 40px;' ng-cloak>
  <md-content>
    <h4>Standard date-picker</h4>
    <md-datepicker ng-model="myDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
</md-content>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
angular.module('datepickerBasicUsage',
    ['ngMaterial', 'ngMessages']).controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.myDate = new Date();
  $scope.minDate = new Date(
      $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
      $scope.myDate.getMonth() - 2,
      $scope.myDate.getDate());
  $scope.maxDate = new Date(
      $scope.myDate.getFullYear(),
      $scope.myDate.getMonth() + 2,
      $scope.myDate.getDate());
  $scope.onlyWeekendsPredicate = function(date) {
    var day = date.getDay();
    return day === 0 || day === 6;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get consistent result across browsers , its best to use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Otherwise you can also use the [toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) .

Lastly you can also write your own service which will get UTC time and apply necessary offsets based on the user locale.

Comment: It would be great if you could give a demo or an example using the above code

Comment: For moment.js , the you can go through the documentation of the main site.
For toLocaleString check this link :[link](http://michelebusta.com/angular-tip-date-and-time-locale-formatting/)

Comment: Would toLocalString() method be used with a $scope object?

Comment: If the date you want to get localized is  : $scope.myDate , then you would use toLocaleString on it.

Comment: Also check out : https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/service/$mdDateLocaleProvider.
Apparently there is an angular service to handle locales.

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much @Rambler