# Angular material datepicker get value as string

Tags: angular8

I have an Angular Material datepicker. I have formatted the date as I wish but now I can't figure out how to send the string which is in the form to the backend.

My html:

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput [formControl]="date" [matDatepicker]="dp" placeholder="Fill in a date">
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

My ts:

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: 'LL',
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    monthYearLabel: 'YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'YYYY',
  },
};


@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MomentDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]},
    {provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MY_FORMATS, },
  ],
})

export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  flightIDInput = new FormControl('WZZ1BW')
  date = new FormControl("");


  constructor(private dataMessageService: DataMessagesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  getMessages() {
    console.log(this.date.value);
    });
  }
}
```

The value in my form is written as 2019-10-18, but when i call it with `this.date` or `this.date.value` it returns [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJGOp.png) massive object. How can I send the string "2019-10-18" to my backend?

Comment: The object has year, month and day attributes. You can extract them with getDay() and so on.

Comment: I'm not able to find these options. How would I do that?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516825/localising-the-date-value-in-angular-material-datepicker

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see how that answers my question

Comment: Try this.date.getDate(), this.date.getYear(), this.date.getMonth() - does that work?

Comment: no. Those options are not available. I am able to check if the object is dirty, valid etc.. It's as if it isn't a date object but something else instead

Comment: I think you need to do this `date = new FormControl(moment())`

Comment: This does not work either.

Comment: I tried it in stackblitz; you can do: `this.date.value._d` - this gives you the date as string, which you can parse. Works but there must be a better way, of course.

Answer (score 1):

You can format your date value by passing it into the below function in TS...

```
formatDate(date) {
  var d = new Date(date),
  month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
  day = '' + d.getDate(),
  year = d.getFullYear();

if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

return [year, month, day].join('-');}
```